# Ajax code working in some parts and not working in others

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my Ajax request to download some data from a database.

There are two codes down below: one that works and one that doesn't, even though they are basically the same. I've also set up later down my code to display the variable (`console.log(location)`) but it just reads `undefined`.

I know the php part of it is working because I also do another `console.log(data)` on success of the ajax call and that returns with the data I entered on my database. What's going on and how do I fix it?

Code that doesn't work:

```
var location;
    
function downloadCoords() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'transformerthing.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            location = data.location;
        },
        error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Code that does work:

```
var mapCode;
var used;
var active;


 function downloadCode() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getMapCode.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            mapCode = data.mapCode;
            used = data.used;
            active = data.active;
        },
        error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: `HTML code that doesnt work` in what way does it not work? errors? warnings? VCR gets reprogrammed?

Comment: looking at both snippets, I suspect you are not really experienced with the asynchronous nature of AJAX calls - both codes are not exactly best practice for asynchronous code

Comment: @JaromandaX no errors,warnings nothing. It just has the location variable undefined even tho I know im being sent the data because of the success console.log(data) which returns whats in my database, to the second part of your awnser. ok...but why does one work and the other doesnt?

Comment: Please show at least the return value of each php file and the console.log(data). If it says "undefined" it means, that data.whatever has not been set correctly - which happens inside the php and no in jquery/js

Comment: does `data` contains `location` anything? would you mind to post `data` here?

Comment: @AlexOdenthal the return value of the php files are basically the same. they are just json_encode(array('location'=>$result[0])); and yes it does Vilas Kumkar

Comment: if you change the name `location` to `Location`, does it work? I suspect having a global named `location` may conflict with `window.location` - a very important "built in"

Comment: it's even possible that there's a page reload happening that you aren't aware of! check the developer tools network tab

Comment: @JaromandaX still no luck, ive tried changing the variable name completly to something random. still doesnt work. ive looked at the network tab and to my eye I dont see any refreshing.

Comment: how odd ... can you show the output of `console.log(data);`

Comment: @WilliamSharp post `data` which is fetched by `transformerthing.php` API call

Comment: also, when you changed location, you only changed `var location` and `location =` ... not `data.location` as well, right

Comment: Object {location: "lat: -43.481199, lng: 172.603098"}    ---- BTW this is for google maps which could a problem later down the road but for now I just want the variable to actually display the data. And yes Jaromanda X

Comment: so, the `console.log(data)` outputs the correct result ... what you are not showing is where you are **using** `location` (or hopefully a different variable name now) where it shows it as undefined - I strongly suspect it's asynchronous code that is tripping you up - i.e. my second comment

Comment: I think the problem is with your data, it suppose to be like `"location": {"lat": "-43.481199","lng": "172.603098"}` or similar, not like `Object {location: "lat: -43.481199, lng: 172.603098"` for sure.

Comment: @JaromandaX Im using the location variable further down the code and I thought that HTML executes it code from top to bottom. But something must be wrong with the asynchronous code, ive tried to add the tag async: false to it but its been depreciated is there anything else I could do, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: @VilasKumkar yeah i can agree you with, it should look different but that shouldnt change it to undefined.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the asynchronous code ... what is wrong is your lack of understanding of how to write asynchronous code ... `top to bottom` is not how javascript works when asynchronous functions are called ... like `$.ajax`

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(data.location)`? What's the output in console?

Comment: @VilasKumkar Still no luck, I think ill just have to fix the asynchronous problem about it

Answer (score -1):

```
//shorthand deferred way

    $.getJSON( "transformerthing.php")
     .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
   }).fail(function(msg){
       console.log(msg)
   });
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var location;

function downloadCoords() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'transformerthing.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            location = data.location;
            console.log(location);
        },
        error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Try it again.

Comment: Hi I just tried this and It kinda worked. It returned with the correct data from the database but the console.log at the end of the code still returns undefined... I thought the way HTML handles the script execution was just linear like for example the lower the down the less priority

Comment: Please read @Jaromanda X 's comment and then go through this introduction https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript?gclid=CjwKEAiA_9nFBRCsurz7y_Px8xoSJAAUqvKC9wPkeT9zFuQVfqLm5wfMsrJohmrGWYekUj3kgA-uPRoC2lrw_wcB